# A clean technique or library to generating emails in Java

Tags: java, email, html-email, templating

Currently our application generates emails for clients via classic "string smashing" mixed in with some String.replace calls.

Does somebody have a suggestion for an easy/elegant/robust way to generate emails?  We are not asking for the fanciest stuff in the world.  Our application uses GWT/Guice so we do not have any jsps/struts pages.

Comment: when you say "generate emails", can you give a sample structure of the mail? Just to understand the amount of static and dynamic content

Comment: `MessageFormatter` plus template messages in resource bundles?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/). There is an example for doing this using [Spring and Velocity](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.5/reference/mail.html#mail-templates). Although I haven't tried this on Guice, I would assume that the example would carry over, for Spring performs the injection of the velocity engine.

Comment: OP mentioned they are using Guice, not Spring, so there's no need for the conditions :)

Comment: @Abdullah, you're right. I didn't read that part of the question well. I've reworded the answer to suit this need.

Answer (score 3):

java.util.MessageFormat.

Alternatively, and much more powerfully, keep your template as XML with tags for the parameters you want to substitute; use XSLT to do the substitution, and XPath to extract just the text from the XML document after processing.